Bound on a series
Given $$S(x)=\sum_{i=r-1}^{\infty}\frac{i^{i}}{i!}x^i.$$
Is it true that for $x$ small enough, there exists a constant $K>0$ such that
$$S(x)\leq K x^r.$$
Clearly we have $$S(x)=x^{r-1}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(i+r-1)^{(i+r-1)}}{(i+r-1)!}x^i.$$
For $x$ small enough the series converges and is smaller than some fixed constant $K$ we get $$S(x)\leq Kx^{r-1} .$$
I managed to get an $x^{r-1}$, but I don't know if it is possible to prove this result with $x^r$.

We use the following quantitative stirling formula (Lower and upper bound of the Stirling's approximation):
$$\forall i \geq 1,~i! \leq \sqrt{2\pi i}~i^i~e^{-i} e^{1/(12 i)}.$$
Assume that $r > 1$ and $0 < x < 1/e$. Then,
$$S(x) \geq \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-1/(12(r-1))} \frac1{\sqrt{r-1}} (xe)^{r-1}.$$
Hence, one canot have $S(x) \leq K x^r$ for $x$ in $(0, \eta)$ with $\eta < 1/e$ and $K < \infty$ which does not depend on $x$. Otherwise,
$$ \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-1/(12(r-1))} \frac1{\sqrt{r-1}} (xe)^{r-1} \leq K x^r,$$
yielding $K = \infty$ since
$$+\infty = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac1{x} \leq K e^{1-r} \sqrt{2\pi(r-1)} e^{1/(12(r-1))}$$

Some discussion.
First of all, the series converges for $|x| < 1/e$ by the ratio test, so that limits  your "$x$ small enough".
As shown here, you have
$$
\frac1{1+W(-x)}=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^k}{k!}x^k
$$
where $W$ is the Lambert function.
So
$$
S(x)=\sum_{i=r-1}^{\infty}\frac{i^{i}}{i!}x^i = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^{i}}{i!}x^i - \sum_{i=1}^{r-2}\frac{i^{i}}{i!}x^i \\
= \frac1{1+W(-x)}-1- \sum_{i=1}^{r-2}\frac{i^{i}}{i!}x^i
$$
Where the finite sum obviously evaluates for any $x$, the term $\frac1{1+W(-x)}$ can get very large depending on $x$, in fact it diverges as $\lim_{x \to 1/e}W(-x) = -(1^-)$.
Hence, if $r$ is small and $x$ is close to $1/e$, then
$
S(x) \simeq \frac1{1+W(-x)} $, i.e. it is determined by  the tail no matter what $r$ is.  Then a  bound on $S(x)$ has nothing to do with $x^r$.
It therefore needs to be specified first what  "$x$ small enough" means, to be able to basically eliminate the tail behavior.
